# django remove least recent many to many entry

Tags: django

In my Django app, I want to allow users to see which profiles they view and which profiles view them. In my `Profile` model I have created 2 fields that accomplish this.

```
viewed = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='viewed_profiles', symmetrical=False)
visitors = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='visitors_profiles', symmetrical=False)
```

I also have the code set up in my views.py file to add profiles to these fields as necessary.  However, I would like to only track and display the most recent 25 or so viewed and visitor profiles. Is there a way to query these fields ordered by date added and delete everything past the first 25 results? Is this possible without creating another field to track the order of the profiles viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation on Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for details of how to do this. You can use [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) to order your objects by date, and use [Python's array slicing syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) to limit the number of results.

An example of showing the most recently added items in your view might look something like this:

```
viewed = Profile.objects.order_by("-date_added")[:25]
```

This doesn't delete everything after 25 - it just fetches the 25 most recent objects (assuming your Profile model has a field called `date_added`).

EDIT: Oops, I think I misread your question.

I think what you'd need to do is have an intermediate model - Django allows you to use a third model as an intermediate one between two different models in a many-to-many relationship. Then you could add the time viewed to that model and store it that way. There's [a good example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in the documentation.

I wouldn't really bother deleting the old ones unless database space was likely to be an issue, but if you need to for any reason, I guess you could set up a signal that was triggered by a new view being created and have that call a function that deletes all but the 25 most recent.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't track the date added for a ManyToMany relationship, so it's not possible to do this reliably without adding a field. To achieve this you'll need to do is add a date field on your ManyToMany intermediary table, then order by that - for example

```
class ProfileViewed(models.Model):
    viewed = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    viewer = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    viewed = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='viewed_profiles', symmetrical=False, through=ProfileViewed)
```

Then you can order your results like so:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(...)
views = ProfileViewed.objects.filter(viewed=profile).order_by('date_added')
```